# Mouse hook and messagebox problem

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, hook

I try to hook the mouse; and my MouseProc is

```
{
   if(nCode==HC_ACTION)
   {
       if(wParam==WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
       {
          MessageBox(NULL,L"",L"",MB_OK);
          return TRUE;
       }
   }
   return CallNextHookEx(hHook,nCode,wParam,lParam);
}
```

I don't know why it gobal-hooks my mouse then generates at lease 10 message boxes for just one leftmouse button click. Why is it wrong ? Also I would like to know how can I hook just a particular process existing in the taskmanager rather than to hook all existing windows ? For this, I have tried to set SetWindowsHookEx()'s fourth parameter the id of the specified thread but it seems nothing actually hooked. (although hHook returned is non-NUll)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How can you hook a particular process? Mouse clicks are global. You mean you want to hook a certain window, which you can do via an injected DLL in which you [subclass said window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

As for why your hook is called several times per click, [MSDN says this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

*"The system calls this function whenever an application calls the GetMessage or PeekMessage function and there is a mouse message to be processed."*

Answer (score 0):

Your hook procedure needs to exist inside a DLL for starters.  That's a requirement for a global hook.  You can install the hook on a thread ID which is the best way, but you can also do some process ID inspection in your hook if you require